Is it a bad idea to clean an air filter vs buying a new one?
Just temporarily until the new one arrives.
And how critical is changing the cabin air filter vs the main one?
09 Camry, 130,000 mile

The problem with cleaning a disposable air filter is that you can transfer dust to the clean side of the filter, which will then be sucked into the engine. That would introduce dust into your air induction system and potentially deposit dust on parts that are supposed to remain hospital-clean. The mass air flow sensor, the throttle body and the turbo can all suffer from dust contamination, not to mention scoring your cylinders and ruining your piston rings from abrasive dust.
For this reason, while waiting for a new filter to arrive, I would not try to clean a disposable air filter unless the engine is so starved for air that I'm getting a check engine light because of it. Then I would see if I could vacuum the filter while it's still installed in its housing so as not to expose the clean side to dust contamination. I would not use compressed air under any circumstances.
A dirty cabin air filter will not affect engine performance. What are potential downsides of not replacing a dirty cabin air filter? Reduced air flow causing --

Possible overheating of the blower motor
Possible freezing-up of the A/C evaporator, totally blocking air flow
Less effective heating and cooling
Ineffective windshield defrost / defog when these are needed for safe driving
Fogging side windows in wet weather
If yours is a charcoal filter, less effective removal of air pollutants

